# Are the white crystals on my American Cheese safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, cheese

I have some American Cheese with fine white crystals on the outside of each slice. They have a gritty texture. Is this a sign that the cheese is spoiled, or just lactic acid salts like aged cheese gets?

Comment: I give the slice a quick rinse and dry with paper towel and the grit is gone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is calcium lactate crystals.  It is safe to eat.  On regular cheeses it is a sign that it is aged well.  For packaged, sliced american cheese I am not sure I would care for it.  But it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: We made grilled cheese sandwiches with it. They tasted fine.

Answer (score 2):

When the protein in milk (casein) breaks down, the amino acid, tyrosine, will form crystals inside the cheese. These are common in some aged Gouda, cheddar, and, I think, manchego. These are perfectly harmless and actually indicate that the cheese is well aged. I don't know if this is the same as crystals on the outside, and American cheese is certainly not aged.